# How to concatenate ASCII converted int with a string in C

Tags: c

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
int main()
{
    char str1[]=asc(20);
    char str2[]="SpApp|";
    strcat(str1,str2);  
    printf(str1);
    getch();  
}
```

I want to write a program which convert `int` to `ASCII` code first and then it concatenate with `SpApp|` and prints the values in `c` program.

Although `printf("%c",20);` also gives `ASCII` conversion, but I'm not getting how to save it in another `char str1[]` and then concatenate it with `char str2[];`

Comment: conio? Seriously, man, update your compiler :-)

Comment: strcat(str1,str2);   is this not working, dude?

Comment: Is it that hard to write "not" instead of "nt", "I'm" instead of "i m", "but" instead of "bt" and so on?

Comment: @paxdiabolo sir, itz the amtter abt concatenating ASCI converted Int with String.I m a new to programmer.If u hv any idea please share with me. Conio is small matter here.or else please edit my above CODE.HELP me.

Comment: Are you in a hurry? Or maybe typing from your phone? Why would you ask for help in such a way people just want to hit you with a dictionary? Maybe english is not your mother tongue but you sure know how to write "but" and "not"..

Comment: c has asc function which returns a character? why would one need it? we can directly write `char x=(char)20;`

Comment: @Anoop Vaidya, strcat(str1,str2); will work when str1 contains sumthing. My problem here is how to assign int to char array,like if i do--int z=20;printf("%c",z);char str1[]=z; DEVC++ compiler says "Invalid initializer". My motto here is to get "(asci converted int)SpAPP|" concatenated string,bt only in C. Any hw. PLZ HELP me.

Comment: I got the problem, now you have many solutions...and kindly follow what others say...no chatting style texts in SO. Stil i wondr y do ppl say SO instd of StackOverflow...lol

Comment: By ascii converted int, do you want 'A' or "65" for input = 65?

Comment: @anishsane The thing is that we can get asci conversion by using printf("%c",20);in c also as x=(char)20; is used in c++.but here i m nt getting how to collect ASCI converted int into String,so as to concatenate with other string. typecasting problem is coming.i m little known. PLZ HELp.

Comment: @"PLZ HELp" : Did none of the answers posted are helpful for your requirement?

Comment: @viveka0690 hmjd's answer solves your problem since 5 hours ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `asc` function returns a single character, not a string, so the array `str1` will not contain the terminating special character `'\0'`.

You have to initialize `str1` properly:

```
char str1[] = { asc(20), '\0' };
```

The *second* problem is that the destination string `str2` is not big enough to contain both the string you start with *and* the extra string you want to add to it. You need to make it big enough to contain both strings:

```
char str2[16] = "...";
```

Comment: @anishsane Or `char str1[] = { ' ', 0 };` :)

Comment: No another note: Does c have asc function which returns a character? why would one need it? we can directly write `char x=(char)20;` instead of `char x=asc(20);`

Comment: @anishsane By seeing that `conio.h` include, I'm guessing the OP is probably using an old Turbo C compiler, which have e.g. `asc` to be somewhat compatible with Turbo Pascal.

Comment: Hmm.. even I have recently used TC++, for creating an exe for a DOS bootable CD :)

Comment: #include"stdio.h"
        //#include"conio.h"
        int main()
        {
        char str1[]={(char)20, '\0'};
        char str2[]="SpApp";
        strcat(str1,str2);
        printf(str1);
        getch();
        }
> THANK U all for helping me.

Comment: @viveka0690 You still don't have enough space in the string you concatenate to, you define it to be just six characters long now which means that the `strcat` call will overwrite the stack memory leading to bad things.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg .Thank you sir for pointing out my mistakes. So to increase space,how much minimum space should i have to assign & where?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg i got where u r pointing towards sir. If I put "char str[20]={(char)20,'\0'};". Is it Ok nw or should i do something else?

Comment: @viveka0690 If you are sure the destination string will never be more than 19 characters (plus terminator) then that's enough.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Sir if i don't know the char space,so wt should i do for dynamic allocation of array??Cause if i left str[blank],it will lead overwriting of stack memory,as i got also in running program.PLEASE Guide me.

Comment: @viveka0690 `strlen(string1) + strlen(string2) + 1; /* +1 for terminator */`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`snprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to create a buffer containing a string with an appended `int`:

```
char str2[32];
snprintf(str2, sizeof(str2), "SpApp|%d", 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using pointers for str1 and str2 like this :

```
char *str1 = "string1";
char *str2 = "string2";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {
    char a[MAX_BUFFER];
    char res[MAX_BUFFER];

    itoa(20, a, 10);
    sprintf(res, "SpApp|%s", a);
    printf("%s", res);
}
```

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg sir. THANKZ i got the required output.

Comment: #include"stdio.h"
        //#include"conio.h"
        int main()
        {
        char str1[]={(char)20, '\0'};
        char str2[]="SpApp";
        strcat(str1,str2);
        printf(str1);
        getch();
        }
> THANK U all for helping me.